# Why do `xwininfo` and `xdotool` give different window ids for the same window?

Tags: xorg, xdotool

In a tab of a terminal emulator (lxterminal) on Lubuntu 18.04, I try to find out its window id by clicking  the same place (where the shell is shown) inside the tab, either by `xwininfo`

```
$ xwininfo -int | grep -Po '(?<=Window id: )[0-9a-zA-Z]+'
31457283
```

or by `xdotool`

```
$ xdotool selectwindow 
35652689
```

Why do `xwininfo` and `xdotool` give me different window ids?

Consequently, the different window IDs lead to different process IDs:

```
$ xdotool getwindowpid 31457283
1480    
$ ps aux | grep -i 1480
t         1480  0.1  0.3 473204 31240 ?        Sl   Nov21  23:18 lxterminal

$ xdotool selectwindow getwindowpid
window 35652689 has no pid associated with it.
```

The problem of different window IDs happens not just inside a tab of lxterminal, but also inside a tab firefox, or in a window of evince. I haven't found  an application by clicking inside whose window the two ways give the same window ID.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu, I would flag it and ask for it to be moved to [unix.se]

Comment: Don't. Software applications are on topic

Comment: The PID stuff is totally irrelevant here. My guess what's happening though is that you're either targeting a different window with `xdotool selectwindow`

Comment: @EvanCarroll   This is very well applicable to Ubuntu, since Ubuntu uses X11 server and all of the mentioned utilities and particularly `xwininfo` comes with Ubuntu by default.  So this has enough to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: On topic? Maybe. Best asked here -- prolly not. But doesn't matter much anyway. The problem can't be reproduced (or at least by me).

Answer (score 1):

These are two different things.

- Window ID: returned by `xdotool selectwindow` and `xwininfo -int`
- Process ID: returned by `xdotool selectwindow getwindowpid` and `xprop | grep _NET_WM_PID` (if you have the [XOrg's Additional Window Properties](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/494183/3285))

The processes ID is the Kernel's process identifier and used for things like killing the process, scheduling the task, etc.

The Window ID is the Window's Server's window identifier. One process can spawn *any* number of Windows, and frequently they spawn more than one. Think about how many dialogs the GIMP has that free-float all over the screen.

In this case the Process ID is just conflating the question, but if you're targeting the **same window** than for any single target you should get the same result for

- `xdotool selectwindow`
- `xwininfo -int`

Run them both on the same line, double click and see what they both say:

```
xwininfo -int | grep -Po '(?<=Window id: )[0-9a-zA-Z]+'; xdotool selectwindow;
```

I installed `lxterminal` and confirmed that whatever you're seeing is unique. I can't reproduce.

Comment: Please read my post for what I asked again.

Comment: @Tim sorry you got me pretty quick before I was finished check it now.